# create user form

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

hai
   i create usercontrols in vb.net txtbox,button,namelist edit grid and userform. all contrils working properly. but user form not working. how to use this userform.please give any idea.

Comment: hello sir i create userform. but i go to add item i create form not come. other controls txtbox buttons are add to tools. but form not add to add item . what i do sir.

Comment: Did you write code that shows the new form? something like: newForm.show() ?

Comment: I would recommend learning a little more English; seriously, it would help us and you answer your questions. As it stands I cannot tell if you are 8 or English is a foreign language to you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use the toolbox to create a new form.  Use the menu:

`Project` | `Add Windows Form...`

**[Alternatives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2xxdce3.aspx)**.

---

1. You are running VB.NET 2005.
2. You have a project with a form "`Form1`".
3. You can see a menu: `File`, `Edit`, `View`, `Project`, ...
4. In the `Project` menu is a menu item `Add Windows Form...`.

Tell me which step doesn't work.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Is it localized (e.g. Hindi)?